# Changes required to allow credentials in options requests

Tags: ajax, servlets, xmlhttprequest, cors, credentials

I have been struggling to meet the CORS requirements to set the allowCredentials flag to true in my options requests. I figured out that in the response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` needs to precisely match the domain of the request origin (not just a wild card). However, I made this change and am still getting this error:

*"XMLHttpRequest cannot load . A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin  is therefore not allowed access."*

Here are my headers:

```
Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:HEAD,POST,GET,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://<MyOrigin>
Access-Control-Max-Age:600
Allow:HEAD,POST,GET,OPTIONS
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:20
Content-Type:<MyContentType>
Date:Fri, 18 Sep 2015 16:19:30 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:<MyLanguages>
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:<MyOrigin>
Origin:http://<MyOrigin>
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://<MyOrigin>?<MyRequest>
User-Agent:<MyUserAgent>
```

As you can see, my `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is *not* a wildcard. What other changes do I need to make to stop getting these errors?

Also, I am getting this in both Chrome and Safari, so I don't think it is a browser specific issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access-control-allow-origin header must be correctly set in the response to the POST paired with the OPTIONS, not just the response to the OPTIONS request.